# How to check CK editor version

Tags: ckeditor

There is an existing CK editor folder in my project. How can I find out it's version? Is it documented?

Answer (score 72):

just make an alert as below in the config.js file, it gives the value

```
alert(CKEDITOR.version);
```

or you can see it directly in the file ckeditor_php4.php, for eg:

```
var $version = '3.6.3';
```

working demo :

```js
alert(CKEDITOR.version);
console.log("CKEDITOR.version ==",CKEDITOR.version);
```

```html
   <head>
                <meta charset="utf-8">
                <title>CKEditor</title>
                <script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.11.4/standard/ckeditor.js"></script>
        </head>
        <body>
                <textarea id="editor1"></textarea>
                <script>
                        CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1' );
                </script>
        </body>
```

Comment: Or at "your_project\vendor\ckeditor\ckeditor\package.json"

`"version": "4.9.2",`

Answer (score 16):

I checked version 3.6 and version info is located f.e. in:

```
/ckeditor/CHANGES.html

CKEditor Changelog

CKEditor 3.6.6.1
```

4.X uses mark down file:

```
/ckeditor/CHANGES.md

CKEditor 4 Changelog
====================

## CKEditor 4.4.1
```

Answer (score 9):

```
CKEDITOR.version
```

running this in the console should tell you the version.

And as for the documentation, you can find it in this URL:

https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR.html#property-version

Answer (score 5):

In latest CKEditors there is a button in default panel "?". Click it and you'll see version number. Otherwise if button not exist you need to check source files. At the beginning they definitely should contain author data & version number.

Comment: You can also type `CKEDITOR.version` in JS console.

Answer (score 2):

> **CKEDITOR.version** will give current version of CKEDITOR

```js
alert(CKEDITOR.version);
console.log("CKEDITOR.version ==",CKEDITOR.version);
```

```html
   <head>
                <meta charset="utf-8">
                <title>CKEditor</title>
                <script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.11.4/standard/ckeditor.js"></script>
        </head>
        <body>
                <textarea id="editor1"></textarea>
                <script>
                        CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1' );
                </script>
        </body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Look inside the `ckeditor/ckeditor.js` file. At the top of the file, you can find the version.

Comment: I don't know why this was downvoted, it was useful for me

Answer (score 0):

For ckeditor 5, you can get the version number by using this in a js file

```
console.log(CKEDITOR_VERSION);
```