# Composer, which version of a (symfony) package within a bundle?

Tags: symfony, composer-php

I installed the `friendsofsymfony/ckeditor-bundle` using these instructions on the [symfony website](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSCKEditorBundle/installation.html). In short there are three steps (for symfony flex):

- `composer require friendsofsymfony/ckeditor-bundle`
- `php bin/console ckeditor:install`
- `php bin/console assets:install public`.

Now when I look at `composer.json` I can only find

```
"friendsofsymfony/ckeditor-bundle": "^1.2",
```

But how though can I discover which version of `ckeditor` (not the bundle) is use? It's not in `composer.json`.

Comment: composer info might help

Comment: Is that what you are looking for ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15872900/how-to-check-ck-editor-version

Comment: @Cerad, composer info does not help unfortunately because it doesn't shoe in there, but thanks to Yoann I was able to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

You must install the CKEditor after the bundle installation [you can see it here](http://friendsofsymfony/ckeditor-bundle) this command permits you to install the version that you want.

By default the latest full version of CKEditor will be installed, but you can configure wich version you want to install [CKEditorInstaller.php](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSCKEditorBundle/blob/2.x/src/Installer/CKEditorInstaller.php).

I hope this can help you